# read file names from files for command line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to run a program requiring comma-separated arrays of files as follows:

```
program -input1 A.txt,B.txt,C.txt -input2 D.txt,E.txt,F.txt -out out.txt
```

My bash attempt:

I'm running command from a folder called ProgramFolder and this folder also contains file1.txt and file2.txt.
file1.txt and file2.txt contain names of files for the program, such as:

```
File1:
A.txt,B.txt,C.txt


File2:
D.txt,E.txt,F.txt
```

But "A.txt, B.txt,C.txt" and "D.txt, E.txt,F.txt" are in a different folder: source 1 and source2 as shown below.

```
## file sources
source1= ~/Band/folder1/
source2= ~/Band/folder1/
```

I have tried running the program this way without success:

```
program -input $source1$(cat file1.txt) -input2 $source2$(cat file2.txt) -out out.txt
```

What is the best way to write a bash for running the program?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to include the paths in `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` and then use `program -input1 $(cat File1.txt) -input2 $(cat File2.txt)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `sed` inside the two command substitutions to process the original files prior their listing within the arguments of the program (thanks to steeldriver for the simplified pattern):

```
program -input "$(sed "s@^\|,@&$source1@g" file1.txt)" -input2 "$(sed "s@^\|,@&$source2@g" file2.txt)"
```

I changed the `sed` commands' default delimiter (`/`) to `@` because both `$source1` and `$source2` will expand to a path containing `/`; nontheless `|` is needed for the alternation.

`sed` commands breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `@`: starts the pattern
- `^\|,`: matches either the start of the line or a `,` character
- `@`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `&`: backreference which will expand to the match
- `$sourceN`: expands to the content of `$sourceN`
- `@`: stops the replacement string / starts the modifiers
- `g`: substitutes every match in the line

Sample output of the `sed` commands for the given values of `$source1`, `$source2` and for the given contents of `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`:

```
user@debian ~/tmp % echo $source1
~/Band/folder1/
user@debian ~/tmp % echo $source2
~/Band/folder2/
user@debian ~/tmp % cat file1.txt 
A.txt,B.txt,C.txt
user@debian ~/tmp % cat file2.txt 
D.txt,E.txt,F.txt
user@debian ~/tmp % sed "s@^\|,@&$source1@g" file1.txt
~/Band/folder1/A.txt,~/Band/folder1/B.txt,~/Band/folder1/C.txt
user@debian ~/tmp % sed "s@^\|,@&$source2@g" file2.txt
~/Band/folder2/D.txt,~/Band/folder2/E.txt,~/Band/folder2/F.txt
```

Comment: Does the match pattern really need to be that complicated? how about just `sed "s@^\|,@&$source1@g" File1`?

Comment: @steeldriver Indeed... it doesn't: It was the result of many wrong attempts. Thanks! Updated

Comment: Many thanks to you two, Kos and steeldriver. The solution is perfect. Just what I wanted!

Comment: @user27976 Glad that it helped :)